# What is a "proxy username and password"

Tags: windows-10, proxy

Ok, I know the question seems rather dumb but please allow me.
I know what the concept of a proxy is. I am not asking "what is a proxy"
I use a proxy here, and I have set it to say "proxy_ip" and "port" in the Proxy settings

Then I read something like this 
[answer to cloning Github with proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31044011/4451521)

and I am what? What "username"? what "password"? I did not know proxys have anything to do with usernames or passwords... or does it

What is this?

Comment: Proxy typically has an account required to use it unless it’s an anonymous proxy

Comment: How do I find this info and if it is anonymous, what do I put in the proxy_username in the linked resource?

Comment: You would have to supply your username for the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different kind of proxies here, a public and a private proxy. Private proxies are typically a paid service where you create an account and then pay for the services that company offers. Whereas public proxies are available to everyone. There are pros and cons to each, but that is for a different discussion.

In the example of the site you linked, they're typing their username and password, of their private proxy account, and then the proxy sites URL.

For example:

```
http://dshowerhandle:SuperSecretPassword@us.paidproxy.com
```

Maybe a better example would be to go try NordVPN. They offer a VPN solution but also offer a proxy service that acts this exact way when connecting to their proxy servers. I use NordVPN mostly as a VPN, but have successfully used the proxy as well. You should also keep in mind that if you setup authentication for a proxy on a web browser, you typically are given a GUI to setup this information. The example you linked and what I wrote, are usually ran from the command line.

Comment: A more typical use of private proxies is those provided by the network itself – for example, corporate networks where the proxy is the only way out from a secured LAN.